# User Input validation for all possibilities

Tags: java, user-input

I am trying to make sure the user only inputs an int and that it falls with the range 10 to 20
I end up getting an error when I first enter an int that is outside the range and then enter a string. I am not sure as to how to continue to ask the user to keep inputting until the number falls between the specified range.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Sweeper!");
    System.out.println("What width of map would you like (10 - 20): ");
    //width = scnr.nextInt()
    while (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Expected a number from 10 to 20");
        scnr.next();
    }
    do {
        width = scnr.nextInt();
        if (width < 10 || width > 20) {
            System.out.println("Expected a number from 10 to 20");
            //width = scnr.nextInt();
        }
    } while (width < 10 || width > 20);
}
```

Comment: please post the error you getting!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Sweeper!");
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("What width of map would you like (10 - 20): ");
        try{
            width = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println(width);
            if (width < 10 || width > 20)
            {
                System.out.println("Expected a number from 10 to 20");
            }
            else
                break;
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Expected a number from 10 to 20");
            scnr.next();
        }
    }
    scnr.close();
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using try and catch?

Comment: @JRob if you don't use `try/catch` how would you handle the exception when user enters `String` instead of `int` ? 

Also check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
while (scnr.hasNext()) {
    if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
        width = scnr.nextInt();
        if (width >= 10 && width <= 20) {
            break;
        }
    }else{
        scnr.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Expected a number from 10 to 20");
}
System.out.println("width = " + width);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are wanting to only accept integer values between the range of 10 and 20 inclusive. If there is a character or string entered, you want a message to be printed out and execution to be continued. If so, then this should be close to what you want. I was originally going to answer this question using a **try-catch** statement however, I noticed that you replied to another answer and said you wanted a different method than using **try-catch**. This code is not 100% functional; you will have to tweak some things but it is very close to what you are looking for I think without using a **try-catch** statement.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int validInput = 0; //flag for valid input; 0 for false, 1 for true

    System.out.println("Welcome to Mine Sweeper!");
    System.out.println("What width of map would you like (10 - 20): ");

    while (validInput == 0) //while input is invalid (i.e. a character, or a value not in range
    {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            width = scanner.nextInt();
            if (width >= 10 && width <= 20)
            {
                validInput = 1; //if input was valid
            }
            else
            {
                validInput = 0; //if input was invalid
                System.out.println("Expected a number from 10 to 20.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You must enter integer values only!");
            validInput = 0; //if input was invalid
        }
        scanner.next();
    }
}
```